# Get all commands from all plugins in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to write a plugin for Eclipse which displays information about the usage of commands, including those from other plugins. I understand that you can create a `CommandManager` and that has methods such as `getAllCommands` and I can do pretty much whatever I like with the Command objects it returns, but these only seem to be for commands that I have given it myself.

Is there a way to get a CommandManager or something equivalent which can give me all of the commands from an Eclipse plugin? Or is there a way I can register a handler for all commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 3.x style plugin you can get the command manager for the currently active window with:

```java
CommandManager commandManager =
   PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getService(CommandManager.class);
```

And the commands with:

```java
Command [] commands = commandManager.getAllCommands();
```

However on a quick test there are over a thousand commands so I'm not sure how useful this is.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be exactly what I was looking for.